# What is this algorithm called? (SSSP)

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, shortest-path, cycle

Observation: For each node, we can reuse it's min path to destination, so we don't have to recalculate it(dp). Also, the moment we discover a cycle, we check if it's negative. If it's not, it will not affect our final answer, and we can say that it is not connected to the destination(wether it does or not).

Pseudo code:

- Given source node u and dest node v
- Initialize Integer dp array that stores min distance to dest node, relative to source node. dp[v]= 0, everything else infinite
- Initialize boolean onPath array that stores wether the current node is on the path we are considering.
- Initialize boolean visited array that tracks wether the current path has been done(initially all false)
- Initialize int tentative array that stores the tentative value of a node. (tentative[u] = 0)
- return function(u).

```
int function(int node){

   onPath[node] = true;

   for each connection u of node{

      if(onPath[u]){ //we've found a cycle
         if(cost to u + tentative[node] > tentative[u]) //report negative cycle
         continue; //safely ignore
      }

      if(visited[u]){
         dp[node] = min(dp[node], dp[u]); //dp already calculated

      }else{
         tentative[u] = tentative[node] + cost to u
         dp[node] = min(function(u), dp[node])
      }

      visited[node] = true;
      onPath[node] = false;
      return dp[node];
}
```

I'm aware this algorithm won't cover the case where destination is part of a negative cycle, but besides that, is there anything wrong with algorithm?
If not, what is it called?

Comment: not sure about correctiveness of your code, but ideas written in pseudo code are quite similar to Bellman-Ford algorithm. https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/bellman_ford.html

Comment: Actually I thought of this algorithm while studying bellman-ford. It just seemed a bit inefficient to me that you would have to consider all the edges each time.

Comment: There is a modification to Bellman_ford which is way faster in practice (still same worst time though) https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/bellman_ford.html#toc-tgt-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "safely ignore" a positive sum cycle because it might be hiding a shorter path. For example, suppose we have a graph with arcs `u->x (10), u->y (1), x->y (10), y->x (1), x->v (1), y->v (10)`. The shortest u-v path is `u->y->x->v`, of length 3.

In a bad execution, the first three calls look like

```
function(u)
    function(x)
        function(y)
```

The out-neighbors of `y` are `v`, yielding a `y->v` path of length 10; and `x`, but the cycle logic suppresses consideration of this arc, so `y` is marked as visited with distance 10 (not 2). As a result we miss the shortest path.

Comment: Actually, the execution of function(u) wasn't done yet. dp[y] would store 1, because only one of the branches is the loop branch, and dp[x] would store 2. The function(u) will take the min of this and return dp[x].

Comment: @timg ah, set it up slightly wrong. Fixed, I think.

Comment: Ahh I did not think of that. Do you think the algorithm would work if, upon discovering the loop, all nodes with inDeg > 1 in the loop would be marked unvisited except the first one?

Comment: @timg Just catching this comment between work meetings. I think so, but I think it would also become worst-case exponential.

Comment: Right that makes sense. Thanks David